# Docker bind mount a folder on removable device not writing files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am having issues writing files to a bing mount on a docker container when the host path is located on an external drive. I can still see the files inside the container, but nothing is written on the external drive.
When I try the same thing with a host path on the hard disk, it works as intended.
I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows 10, here's my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    container_name: busy
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - <removable_drive_letter>\busybox_data\:/mnt/data/
```

I start the container and try to write a file to the mapped path:

```
/mnt/data # echo test > test.txt
/mnt/data # ls
test.txt
```

But there's nothing on the host path

```
D:\
λ cd busybox_data\

D:\busybox_data
λ ls
```

If I delete the container and start it again, I can see the files, so they are persisted somewhere, but not on the removable drive. The container will not start without the drive attached because of the mapping, but even if I replace it with another dive, as long as it has the same letter, it will work and the file will be there.

Any help will be appreciated.